# ASP.NET MVC Server.MapPath giving full path in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, server.mappath

I am uploading a file with

```
var filename = Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/Content/UserContent", Path.ChangeExtension(newName,Path.GetExtension(attachments.FileName))));
attachments.SaveAs(filename);
```

it works great except that in Internet Explorer it gives the full path "C:\Users\okke\Desktop\GEWOONEENMAP OK\etags.txt" instead of just saying "etags.txt", how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) on the result to get only the file name e.g.

```
attachments.SaveAs(Path.GetFileName(fileName));
```

If the value of `fileName` is a file path it will return the file name (with ext), if it is already a valid file name it will just return the same value.

Comment: Yes but now it says SaveAs requires a rooted path, when I am saving the file to the database (just the name), it saves the whole path name except just "etags.txt"

Comment: Well that wasn't your original question, however, to fix it all you need to do is wrap your `Path.ChangeExtension` call with `Path.GetFileName` instead of in the `SaveAs` call.